# Not enough /boot space running "sudo make install" while compiling Linux kernel

Tags: kernel, compiling

```
$ df -h /boot/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p2  705M  173M  481M  27% /boot
```

I tried to compile Ubuntu Linux kernel (v5.11.16)

```
fakeroot debian/rules clean // fine
make menuconfig // fine
make // fine
sudo make modules_install // fine
```

but when I do `sudo make install`, the `/boot` partition goes full very quickly and the install command reports error:

```
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.16+ with 1.
```

Please help, this my first time :)
// Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: You didn't by any chance build your kernel inside /boot, did you? Just asking...

Comment: I have 2 kernels in /boot on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine that I am writing this from, and they cosume a grand total of 21 MB in /boot. Even your used 173 MB before `make install` seems excessive to me. You might want to clean up old unused kernels.

Comment: How to remove old kernels: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels

Comment: @HuHa, I'm using git to fetch the source (git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel-test/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/mainline-crack), and of-course the directory is in different partition. I think 481MB available should be more than enough.

Comment: During `make menuconfig`, did you enable an excessive amount of kernel modules that might possibly inflate the kernel size so much? Did you enable debug info? Or did you stick with the defaults?

Comment: @HuHa, I'm running the 5.11.16, I've just fetched the source, applied a small patch then tried to compile it. I copied the config from my running kernel and have not modified anything. How do I enable debug info? I'm noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1 flag to make command. It works.

```
make INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1 modules_install
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are compiling the kernel then it is best to do that outside the `/boot` directory. This is the process that I follow when compiling from source:

1. Download or clone the desired kernel source to a directory on a device with at least 25GB of storage available
2. Go into the source directory
3. Copy your existing config from `/boot`

   ```
   cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
   ```
4. Use the Terminal-based configuration tool

   ```
   make menuconfig
   ```
5. Add/remove options based on your hardware
6. Compile the kernel with Clang

   ```
   make CC=clang -j12
   ```
7. Install the kernel

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```
8. Update grub

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
9. Reboot

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

That’s usually all there is to it.